# Using paintComponent() and high CPU Usage

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to create a funny game, which includes a Wheel, a ball. Each time the user click on the button, the ball will roll and randomly land on one slot in the wheel.Things are OK, to create the Wheel, I put the image and the ball (Oval Object) on a separate `JPanel`. The functional behavior are good as i expect. However, each time i run the program, the CPU sounds loudly and the usage of Java application often take up to 25%.

That's quite terrible. After a while doing some tests, it seems that the error is inside my `painComponent()` overridden methods as the Java repeatedly call this method nonstop. A more throughout investigation suggest the the problem is the method `getScaledInstance` which is used to scale the image inside panel. It appears to me that if i remove this method, the `paintComponent()` will not be called repeatedly.

However, things are I don't know how to make the image scaled without `getScaledInstance`. Note that I tried to make a copy based on the sample of MadProgrammer [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

So, what do you think about it? Is there any way to set the background image, keep the aspect ratio and not over calling `paintComponent()` method? Note that I did try to use `Thread.sleep` but it doesn't work very well.

This is quite struggling for me. Anyway, thank for reading!

```
public class WheelPanel2 extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int time = 0;
    private Image scaled = null;
    private int scaleWidth = 300;
    private int scaleHeight = 300;

    public WheelPanel2() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("img/Basic_roulette_wheel_1024x1024.png"));
            scaled = image.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setSize(400, 400);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));


        double scaleFactor = Math.min(1d, getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), getSize()));
        int scaleWidth = (int) Math.round(image.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
        int scaleHeight = (int) Math.round(image.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
        Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    }

    /**
     * The Paint Method - Create the image of the Wheel and the Ball
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        double scaleFactor = Math.min(1d, getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), getSize()));

        //TRUE WIDTH AND HEIGHT
        int scaleWidth = (int) Math.round(image.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
        int scaleHeight = (int) Math.round(image.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
        scaled = image.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;
        int x = (width - scaled.getWidth(this)) / 2;
        int y = (height - scaled.getHeight(this)) / 2;

        g.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this);
        System.out.println("PAINT");

    }



    /**
     * These two methods are used to automatically resize the wheelpanel and the ball
     */
    private double getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {

        double dScale = 1d;

        if (original != null && toFit != null) {

            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(original.width, toFit.width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(original.height, toFit.height);

            dScale = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);

        }

        return dScale;
    }

    private double getScaleFactor(int iMasterSize, int iTargetSize) {

        double dScale;
        if (iMasterSize > iTargetSize) {

            dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;

        } else {

            dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;

        }

        return dScale;

    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HI THERE");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new WheelPanel2(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);

    }
}
```

If you try to run the program, you will know that the paintComponent are called non-stop.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], otherwise we can't really run your program as you asked.

Comment: Just fix it. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: One way to get image(s) for an example (an MRE, as described by @RealSkeptic) is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than scaling the Image yourself, let the Graphics do it, by calling the [drawImage method which takes width and height arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,int,int,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29):

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int width = image.getWidth(this);
    int height = image.getHeight(this);
    float scale = Math.min(
        (float) getWidth() / width,
        (float) getHeight() / height);

    width = (int) (width * scale);
    height = (int) (height * scale);

    int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
    int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;

    g.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, this);
}
```

On most platforms, this will take advantage of the system’s graphics acceleration to scale the image.

If you want to be certain that the equivalent of SCALE_SMOOTH is used to scale the image, [set the appropriate RenderingHint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint%28java.awt.RenderingHints.Key,java.lang.Object%29):

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

    int width = image.getWidth(this);
    int height = image.getHeight(this);
    float scale = Math.min(
        (float) getWidth() / width,
        (float) getHeight() / height);

    width = (int) (width * scale);
    height = (int) (height * scale);

    int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
    int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;

    g.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, this);
}
```

Comment: But i want to keep the aspect ratio of the image. And make sure that when resizing the panel, this ratio is fixed.

Comment: Updated to preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't understand much of a swing but can you try to call `getScaledInstance` only one time in the constructor and there to create `Image scaled`?

```
 //part of the class properties
private Image scaled = null;
//other properties

public WheelPanel() {
    this.this_class = this;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("img/Basic_roulette_wheel_1024x1024.png"));
        //Create only one scaled image and after that use it in paintComponent method
        scaled = image.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight,  Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setSize(400, 400);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));      
}
```

If this for some reason does not work you can try to create `Image scaled` only one inside `paintComponent` method. Example:

```
//part of the class properties
private Image scaled = null;
/**
* The Paint Method - Create the image of the Wheel and the Ball
*/
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    double scaleFactor = Math.min(1d, getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), getSize()));
    int scaleWidth = (int) Math.round(image.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
    int scaleHeight = (int) Math.round(image.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    if(scaled == null)
    {
        scaled = image.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight,  Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    }

    int width = getWidth() - 1;
    int height = getHeight() - 1;
    int x = (width - scaled.getWidth(this)) / 2;
    int y = (height - scaled.getHeight(this)) / 2;
   g.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this_class);

 }
```

Edit: I saw how you modify the example with the constructor. Please try this constructor:

```
//part of the class properties
private Image scaled = null;


public WheelPanel2() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("img/Basic_roulette_wheel_1024x1024.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setSize(400, 400);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));


    double scaleFactor = Math.min(1d, getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), getSize()));
    int scaleWidth = (int) Math.round(image.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
    int scaleHeight = (int) Math.round(image.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    scaled = image.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

}
```

Good luck to all!

Comment: Believe me, the behaviour is not the same ;((( I also test several time and puts method on constructor. The outcome is that while the paintComponent is not called non-stop, the behavior is totally different to that i expect.

Comment: Let the `paintComponent` to be called many times. If I understood you correctly your problem is `getScaledInstance` is called many times and it take a lot of resources. My proposal is to call `getScaledInstance` only one time. Please, can you tell me what is the behaviour when you make the modifications which I suggest?